# How to navigate Soup data structure when tag contain full stop

Tags: beautifulsoup

How does one navigate Beautiful Soup data structures (xml/html) which have tags containing full stops?

Example:

```
<body>
   <body.head>
      <headline>
```

I would like to access headline directly without the use of find.

Thanks,
Marcel

Comment: use a regex to achieve it without bs4, but why wouldn't you use the find function ?

Comment: Can you post an actual example of your html and what exactly you are trying to extract?

Comment: what did you mean by "without the use of find."??